# ASP.Net Model Binder - Ignore Not Mapped Properties

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, entity-framework-core, odata, model-binding

I am working with ASP.Net Core 5, Entity Framework Core 6, and using ODATA controllers with an EDM model.  The model I am working with has several properties, including a `[NotMapped]` property.  I have a React SPA that gets an entity from the controller, including the `[NotMapped]` property.  When I post this entity back to my controller from the react app.  The controller uses `[FromBody]` attribute to deserialize the JSON into a complex .NET object.  However, the model fails to bind because of the [NotMapped]` property.  If I remove this not mapped property in the React app on the client side before posting to the controller, the model binder works fine.  However, this is not an acceptable solution, since this means my code will break anytime I add a not mapped property to my models without updating the React client to deal with this.  The React client has no understanding of which properties are mapped or not mapped.  Is there a way to get the model binder to just ignore properties that do not exist in the model, instead of having the model fail to bind completely?

Here is my model:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() { }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
        
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
        
}
```

And here is my controller Get action:

```
    [ODataRoute("{id}")]
    public Person Get([FromODataUri] int id)
    { return db.Persons.Find(id); }
```

The controller successfully gets the `Person`, including the `[NotMapped]` `FullName` property from the model and returns the model to the React client.

When I update the model on the React client and want to update Person, I call the Put method of this controller:

```
    [ODataRoute("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int id, [FromBody] Person person)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
        if (id != person.Id) return BadRequest();

        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Updated(person);
    }
```

However, the `Person` object is null in the controller because it does not recognize the `[NotMapped]` `FullName` property of `Person`.  I presume this, because if I remove this property from the JSON before POST'ing the data to the controller the model binder properly populate the `Person` object.

Is there a simple way to tell the model binder to simple ignore extra properties that do not exist as mapped properties of the model it is trying to bind, or do I have to write a complete custom model binder to do this?

***Edit***
Here is an example JSON payload that results in the model not binding, and the Person entity in my controller is null:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44304/rest/$metadata#Persons/$entity",
  "Id": 1,
  "FirstName": "Jimmy",
  "LastName": "Johnson",
  "FullName": "Jimmy Johnson",
}
```

Note the `FullName` property is `[NotMapped]`. When included in the JSON payload in my controller, it will not deserserialize.  The `person` object is Null.  Also notice there `@odata.context` does not interfere with the deserialization, even though it is not in the model.  I assume the Odata inputformatter knows to expect that and ignores it.

If I send the same payload as above, but omit the `FullName` property, the JSON deserializes and the `person` object is populated.

I would like to figure out how to make it so that `FullName` or any `[NotMapped]` property is ignored, rather than causing the deserialization to fail.  I am hoping for a solution that doesn't make me have a custom inputformatter for each entity type, and one that does not require me to make changes for every new `[NotMapped]` property I add to any of my models.  It seems like there should just be an option in System.Text.Json options that tells the deserializer to ignore properties that don't exists for the model, just like `@Odata.context` which is ignored.  However, I have not seen such an option.

Comment: You could try to create a View Model (such as PersonViewModel) which contains all of the required properties (Not use the Not Mapped attribute), this model is used to transfer data between client and server side. Then, use the Person model is used to map the database table and access data.

Comment: I have run into this same problem where the model binding will not ignore incoming properties that do not exist on the model resulting in a null action parameter. My roadblock is that the grid I am using on the client will not allow me to customize the JSON payload being sent back. It will only send up the (full) model that was initially bound to the grid. However, when creating POSTING a new entity, I want CreatedOn and like properties ignored.

Comment: @Jason - The solution I ended up going with was prefixing all my [NotMapped] properties with an underscore.  So FullName became _FullName.  Then in the component that I use that makes all the OData API requests, I mutate the model by removing any property prefixed with an underscore.  Not super elegant, but works pretty well and doesn't require creating a separate view model, or writing different code for each model that contains a [NotMapped] property. Maybe sometime in the future there will be a more permanent solution.